# Why doesn't my Windows Form get redrawn when the window is resized?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a simple Form such as the following:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PaintTest
{
   class PaintTest : Form
   {
      int _counter = 0;

      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
         Application.Run(new PaintTest());
      }

      protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
      {
         e.Graphics.DrawString(_counter.ToString(), new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 10.0f), Brushes.Blue, 10.0f, 10.0f);
         _counter++;
      }
   }
}
```

When the window is resized, the counter doesn't appear to update on the screen, even though `OnPaint()` is getting called and the counter incremented. How do I make the Form repaint itself as the window is resized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your class, e.g. in its constructor:

`SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);`

Comment: If the form has an InitializeComponent() call, would you set that style before or after it? or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Svish, I've just tested it and it doesn't matter. Re: the fast answer - I'd just worked it out after a frustrating morning and wanted to share the love! :-)